# Bittorrent protocol: # of connections between two peers (seeder+leecher)

Tags: bittorrent

I plan to stop using webdav for listing available files at some little bittorrent seedbox, and "share" all my downloads through a global `all_my_downloads.torrent` file (DHT disabled); this way I *can transparently use remote NAS on a seedbox instead of chaosing up my netbook's ssd with many Gb's of junk including "only recent music downloads"*

Problem is, that a speed of a single connection is limited by either by ISP, or by a ssh tunnel uncertain limits about one connection speed in a -D tunnel (hello, friendly ISP who makes me use corkscrew and ssh to avoid buggy http proxy).

When files are at Webdav (basically HTTP) server, it is easy to download them in 5-6 streams to utilize all bandwidth; just use `aria2c` instead of wget. When a normal torrent is used, multiple peers are giving multiple connections (somehow easier for ssh to keep in single tunnel) - so no lose in speed. (however, I plan to get rid of ssh completely by seeding from proxy-allowed ports like 80/443/5190).

But the single connection speed, now, may get limited by a proxy.

What is the # of file pieces that one client may download from other client at a same time from a same serving port? Multiple connections are wished.. will be checked.

Comment: A "connection" in Bittorrent is for a piece of a file, not an entire file like in HTTP downloads.  Typically you will be transferring one piece at a time from a peer.  If there are more peers, then there can be more transfers in flight.  So if more than one person downloads from you using a torrents, they will be trading pieces between themselves in addition to with you.  One-to-one file transfers are a bit inefficient over Bittorrent (but rather resilient and very tolerant of network dropouts given how most Bittorrent applications work).  Bittorrent is for one to many or many to many, really.

Comment: @ultrasawblade tell that to Bittorrent Sync devs, really - I foresaw that BT file sync will be *invented* one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One connection per peer per torrent.

Ref. http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=542804#p542804